# (Almost) Infinite Duplicate classes (Android Java)

Tags: gmail-api

I've tried to send an email with Gmail API and when I build the app, I get this lovely error message (just part of it):
[image]

My Gradle:

```
android{
   [...]
   packagingOptions{
        pickFirst("google/protobuf/empty.proto")
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    // firebase

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.9.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0")


    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // gmail
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1")
    implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20220404-2.0.0")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
    implementation("javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01")
    [...]
```

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

**update**

I THOUGHT it turned out it was just one file that broke it all, I added

```
pickFirst("google/protobuf/field_mask.proto")
```

and it worked. BUT than it asked me another file, and another, and it seems something is still broken...